# git lfs and BFS

Tags: git, git-lfs, bfg-repo-cleaner

BFG for git LFS supports the option `--strip-blobs-bigger-than`

Does git-lfs itself support tracking files based on size, or only based on extension? The git-lfs-track man page seems to only support specifying by extension, so I'm guessing BFS just uses that option to automatically determine a file extension list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `git-lfs` doesn't support tracking by size, partly due to the way the filters work. See https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/282 .

You are better off to pre analyse and decide which extensions you need to externalize to LFS.